# move_base - moving backwards

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to configure move_base to follow paths forward and backward?

I have been able to create paths composed of forward and backward segments with SBPL, but move_base tries always to complete the path rotating and moving forward.

Thanks,

Robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12578/move_base---moving-backwards/) by [Robotnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1119/robotnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [pose_follower](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pose_follower) as local planner in move_base. It's not really documented and needs some parameter tuning, but it will follow your originally planned path very closely. I believe both DWA and Trajectory Rollout will try to optimize your path and avoid backwards motion.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robotnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1119/robotnik/) on 2012-01-11**:
You are right, thanks.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-11**:
Keep in mind that that topic is not where move_base get's its global plan from. If you look at the source (line 362ish of sbpl_lattice_planner.cpp) you'll see that it does set yaw angle for the plan move_base gets (following the BaseGlobalPlanner interface).

**Comment by [Robotnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1119/robotnik/) on 2012-01-11**:
Hi, thank you, I will test this right now. I have just realized that the path published by /move_base_node/SBPLLatticePlanner/plan is the sequence of poses, but without orientation information (just x,y fields are used), so it might be hard for the planner to decide where to move forward and backward...